# Access variables from another class

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm a beginner at Objective-C programming and I need to access data stored in a NSMutableArray from another class for populating a TableView, however I only get null. 
The variables I need to access are in the class below:

FunctionsController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FunctionsController : UIView {
    @public NSMutableArray *placesNames;    
    NSMutableArray *placesAdresses; 
    NSMutableArray *placesReferences;
    NSMutableArray *placesLatitudes;
    NSMutableArray *placesLongitudes;
    NSArray *list;
}
@end
```

In this other class I'm trying to access the data but I only get null as result.

SimpleSplitController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    FunctionsController *arrays = [[FunctionsController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *names = [arrays->placesNames];

    // Set up the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 10;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

return cell;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
FunctionsController *arrays = [[FunctionsController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *names = [arrays->placesNames];
```

First you are allocating the FunctionsController again. That gives you a clean new instance with no data in its variables. If that 'init' is not putting that in those variables you aren't gonna get anything from them.

A second problem I see is that you are accessing the variable directly. I would use properties instead. You declare a property by doing this in your FunctionsController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *placesNames;
```

And adding this to your FunctionsController.m:

```
@synthesize placesNames;
```

And then you access the property by doing this:

```
NSMutableArray *names = arrays.placesNames;
```

Finally I would recommend you to use Core Data for storing that data instead because it seems that it should belong to a SQL database. More about Core Data here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: How do I initialize the arrays variable? FunctionsController *array; only?

Comment: If you want your FunctionsController to hold your data and still being able to call it from any class without assigning it to a variable so that it stays instantiated you should try using the Singleton pattern on the FunctionsController. Information about Singleton pattern is here http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
FunctionsController *arrays = [[FunctionsController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *names = [arrays->placesNames];
```

Unless you're setting up `placesNames` in the init method of FunctionsController then it will either be empty or nil.

Take a look at [singletons](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) on objective-c.